# Convert a pandas column containing dictionary into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Dataframe

`temp = pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['P1', 'P2'], 'Dictionary': [{'value1': 0.31, 'value2': 0.304}, {'value2': 0.324}]})`

```
  Person                    Dictionary    
0  P1  {'value1': 0.31, 'value2': 0.304}
1  P2                  {'value2': 0.324}
```

I want an output in this format:

```
temp1 = pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['P1', 'P1', 'P2'], 'Values_Number': ['value1', 'value2', 'value2'], 'Values': [0.31, 0.304, 0.324]})
```

I tried using this:

```
temp['Dictionary'].apply(pd.Series).T.reset_index()
```

```
  Person Values_Number  Values
0     P1        value1   0.310
1     P1        value2   0.304
2     P2        value2   0.324
```

But i am not able to concat this with the previous Dataframe. Also, we would be chances of error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, We could use[`Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) in order to build a new `DataFrame` that we can `melt` with [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt)

```
new_df = (pd.DataFrame(temp['Dictionary'].tolist(), index=temp['Person'])
            .reset_index()
            .melt('Person', var_name='Values_Number', value_name='Values')
            .dropna()
            .reset_index(drop=True))
print(new_df)
```

---

```
  Person Values_Number  Values
0     P1        value1   0.310
1     P1        value2   0.304
2     P2        value2   0.324
```

---

it is much more efficient to use `pd.DataFrame(df['Dictionary'].tolist())` than `.apply(pd.Series)`. You can see when you should use `apply` in you code [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

---

This is result for `apply(pd.Series)` obtained in this publication.

```
%timeit s.apply(pd.Series)
%timeit pd.DataFrame(s.tolist())

2.65 ms ± 294 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
816 µs ± 40.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `tolist` and `melt` should work

`pd.DataFrame(df['Dictionary'].tolist()).set_index(temp['per']).reset_index().melt(id_vars='Person', value_vars=['value1', 'value2'], var_name='Values_Number').dropna()`

```
  Person Values_Number  value
0  P1    value1         0.310
2  P1    value2         0.304
3  P2    value2         0.324
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code